# Computation of triple nested loops as a convolution product?

Tags: fourier-transform, fftw, convolution

I'm trying to compute efficiently the following
\begin{equation}
A_j = \sum_{l'=1}^{\infty}\sum_{k= 0}^{K-1} L_{l'}T_ke^{2\pi i \frac{k}{K}j}\epsilon_{l',k}
\end{equation}
for $j = 0,1, \ldots, K-2,K-1$, where $L_l$ (dimension $NL$) and $T_k$ (dimension $W$) are 1D vectors of complex numbers and $\epsilon$ is a 2D matrix (dimensions : $L \times W$) of complex numbers.

Numerically, I'm performing the summation over $l'$ from $1$ to $NL$, where $N$ is an integer that has to be chosen sufficiently large (to satisfy conditions unimportant in this context), therefore yielding
\begin{equation}
A_j = \sum_{l'=1}^{NL}\sum_{k= 0}^{K-1} L_{l'}T_ke^{2\pi i \frac{k}{K}j}\epsilon_{l'\text{mod} L,k},
\end{equation}
a truncated summation over $l'$ and the index of $\epsilon_{l'\text{mod} L,k}$ being taken with the modulo.

While a straightforward (but naive) implementation of $A_j$ in terms of three nested for loops (two for the above double sum and a third that ranges over all $j$) works fine, it is terribly slow, especially considering that this implementation is to be repeated for every time step (and there are many of them).

I'm thus looking for an efficient implementation of the above, which looks very much like a 2D separable convolution product. This would allow one to make use of FFT's to compute it quite efficiently, taking advantage that in the frequency domain, a convolution becomes a multiplication of complex numbers.

Does anybody have any idea ?

Comment: What does the $(0)$ attached to $\varepsilon_{l',k}$ imply?

Comment: Also, where is the third loop you are speaking of? I see only two.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth, The $(0)$ stands for the initial time and could have been omitted, so that $\epsilon_{l',j}$ are just complex numbers. The third loop comes from the fact that I need to compute $A_j(t)$ for all $j$.

Comment: I see. I think that you can make your readers' intuition easier to come if you omit everything that's really not important to your question. This includes the $(0)$ on epsilon, as well as the $(t)$ on all symbols that have such. Simplify the notation until it reflects the core of the problem.

Comment: Similarly, the factor $f(t)$ clearly has no relevance to the problem formulation.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth, I've edited the initial post following your remarks. I hope it's clearer so.

Comment: What is L in the mod? NL? Or something else?

Comment: $L$ is the number of rows of the $\epsilon$ matrix. So, instead of performing the sum from $1$ to $\infty$, I do it $N$ times from $1$ to $L$, with a periodic visit of the matrix elements $\epsilon_{l',j}$.

Comment: Get rid of the $(t)$ as well -- that also doesn't have anything to do with it :-)

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth, Right, I edit the initial post and delete about the (t) dependence. I'm also considering to ask the question tomorrow to the DSP community, maybe they should have an idea, since they play everyday with convolution :-)

Comment: It's somewhat confusing to have L as one of the functions and also the rows of the matrix, and L prime as a summation variable as well doesn't help. But can't you do this first with L (the number of rows of epsilon) FFTs effectively doing the K and J loops, and then summing over the results (the L prime loop) weighing with the L function to get the answer?

Comment: @IanBush : Can you please clarify, just for sure ? So, you propose to perform the $k$ and $j$ summations with a 2D cyclic convolution (expedited by the inverse FT of the product of the FTs of $\epsilon$ and $e^{2\pi i kj/K}$) leaving a $L\times W$ matrix (same dimensions as $\epsilon$) and to weigth that result with the coefficients of the kernel $L$ ? This is something similar I had in mind when asking the question, but I wanted to perform a cyclic convolution over $l'$, since the formulation of the problem seems appealing in that direction.

Comment: Very busy today - will try to find time to think properly about this and answer  properly when I can. Given the L prime sum is periodic I have also thought you might be able to use Fourier methods in that direction, but I would need to think more and what I say above looks simpler to me. Take the L function out the k summation, Fourier Transform for each of the L independent rows of epsilon, and sum as appropriate

Comment: Regarding the idea you proposed, is a treatment of the $k$ and $j$ loops by means of fft not involving a summation over $j$, by definition of the underlying convolution product ? If so, it is not the same problem as mine since sums are made only over $l'$ and $k$. The third loop's purpose is only to range over all $j$ values.

Comment: I didn't mention any summation over j, just FT T(k)epsilon(k,L) for each independent L inot the j domain, then perform the summations over l prime. No summation over j.

Comment: If I take the FT of T(k)epsilon(k,L) for each independent L, how can I get rid of $e^{2\pi i kj/K}$ that depends both upon $j$ and $k$ ? That's what puzzling me with your idea.

Comment: If you take the FT by summing over k it doesn't depend on k any more, it just depends on j.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us write it as
\begin{equation}
A_j = \sum_{l'=1}^{NL} S_{jl'}L_{l'} 
\end{equation}

Where

\begin{equation}
S_{jl'} =  \sum_{k= 0}^{K-1}[T_k\epsilon_{l'\text{mod} R,k}]e^{2\pi i \frac{k}{K}j}
\end{equation}

(I'm using R for the number of rows, the re-use of L is much too confusing)

This last expression is clearly the discrete Fourier Transfrom of the term in the square brackets. Thus evaluting the FT for a given l' gives you the terms for all j in  $S_{jl'}$. Thus to calculate $A_j$ evaluate the FT for all l', and then perform the sum in the first equation, which is simply a matrix vector multiplication.

You can improve this further by exploiting the mod function which means there are in fact only R independent FTs you need to evaluate, as for higher l' the terms will just repeat.

If I have this right this will reudce the number of operations from $O(NL\times K^2)$ to $O(R\times K \times log( K ))$, assuming the Fourier transform part dominates the matrix vector multiply.